# Calculating Sub-totals as a percentage of Grand-total in Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I know this has been asked time and again by people all over the net, but I can't for the life of me figure out why my solution isn't working.

I have a bunch of groups, and in each group's footer I have a running total which acts as a sub-total for that group.  At the very bottom of the page, I have a running total which adds all these sub-totals together to give a grand-total.  This all works great.

To the right of each sub-total (group footer), I have a formula field which calculates what proportion of the grand-total this sub-total represents.
i.e. if the Grand-total is 4, and the sub-total is 1, the formula field displays 25%.

The problem is that for each group in the report, the Grand-total hasn't yet been fully counted (until the last group), and so the percentages are being calculated against incomplete Grand-totals.

To combat this, I've tried using the `WhilePrintingRecords;` function on my percentage formula fields to ensure that the sub-total percentages are not calculated until the 2nd pass of the report, by which time the Grand-total should be fully calculated.

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
If {@LoggedToday} > 0 Then
    {#LoggedToday}  / {#TotalLoggedToday} * 100
Else
    0
```

It's not working though! It's literally had no impact what-so-ever :o(

Does anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're using a running total to calculate a grand total.

Instead, I suggest creating a Crystal formula for your percentage, in the form:

`Sum ({` *numeric field* `}, {` *grouping item* `}) % Sum ({` *numeric field* `})`